# Remove unwanted Favicon from constantly appearing in unrelated URLs

Tags: favicon

Remove unwanted Favicon from constantly appearing in unrelated URLs
A favicon is constantly appearing in the URL in totally unrelated websites.
How can I get rid of this favicon?

Answer (score 3):

Can be more specific? What browser? What site? What favicon?

Also, this screams cache. Try emptying your browser's cache and refreshing (F5). Better yet, just hard refresh without clearing your cache if you don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I second the Cache issue. I would also try [Ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) (assuming your on a windows machine)